# Balancing people from another world with people from the mother-world

Tags: alternate-reality

[image]

Average adult male weakling from the mother-world: can bench (larsen press style, so no arch and no leg drive) a pathetic 300kg/661lbs without ever training.

Average adult male from our world:  can probably bench their own bodyweight after 2-3 months of training and will probably peak at a lifetime limit of 180kg/397lbs after decades of training if they started young enough.

The strongest humans ever recorded on this planet are as strong as the weakest people from the mother-world.

[image]

In this setting a few people are sometimes randomly spawned from our world to another universe in the ''mother-world'' this planet is harsher and everyone living here is already adapted with immense natural inborn strength, speed, agility, power, coordination, stability, balance, flexibility and as intelligent as modern humans from our world, yet they are technologically developed in different ways. They don't have smartphones but have brain implants or other body augmentations.

I need a way to make those modern humans survive in this new world, are there real world examples where slight similarities can be found and applied to this?

Comment: It is unclear what the modern humans need to survive "against". Survive against the giant lions and tigers of stone-age Mother World? Or survive financially in the economy of computer age Mother World without going bankrupt? Please explain in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Our flimsy ancestors, without fangs, claws, venom, horns or speed/mass, have managed to survive and emerge in an environment crawling with species which had them (lion, tigers, hyenas, elephants, rhinoceros, cave bear, wolves, etc. etc.), without having the benefits of modern technology.

How did they do it?

Group work and brain. If the people of your mother world fall into the stereotype of "all muscles no brain" a decently smart person can manage to survive by using their brain.

Also don't forget that mice thrive among us, even though they are nowhere comparable in strength to a bank teller, just to name a job not famous for the physical prowess of its practitioners. So, bench pressing tons is not all.

Answer (score 1):

### 1) The strongmen have better morals

Lifting from Out Of The Silent Planet here. The strongmen are saintly and kind and incredibly considerate towards us weaklings, and give us far more grace than we deserve.

We're basically a race of crybullies in comparison, and yet are tolerated and helped, which is invariably misinterpreted by us as weakness or stupidity. How long until they're forced to take remedial measures?

### 2) The strongmen have morals so bad that their society is weak

A little like Dutch said. The strongmen are in a constant state of civil war and anarchy. We have guns, they have guns, physical strength really doesn't assure victory by itself.

### 3) We resist disease or poison better

Self explanatory. It's great being able to bench press gazillions of kilograms but not so great when flu is like the Black Death.

### 4) We're hot

Unexpectedly, our slim bodies are viewed as incredibly attractive.
Britney Spears may not have great physical prowess or singing talent but still rose to the top of her industry in the day, partially because of how she looked.
You could introduce dynamics that differ for the sexes. Maybe our women are attractive but not our men, or vice versa, or roll with something more subtle.
Hybrid offspring may be a compromise or better than either parent species.

### 5) Tinyness is a niche

If real gnomes or dwarves existed, they'd make great data techs, electricians, exterminators, etc; any job that has fitting into crawl spaces as a major competitive example.